# How to create a UI like Bottomsheet in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a UI similar to the image provided using flutter. 
The data is coming from A web service and is getting displayed inside the grid view. I want to add the feature that on click of the element the details should appear on the card that is scrolled from the bottom. And the users can scroll it up and can view more details.

[here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDAZr.jpg)

I'm able to pass the value from the grid to another page called details.dart and able to display the details. But the clients now require the data to be loaded on the view that slides up

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you are looking for [Bottomsheet for Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-beginners-guide-to-using-the-bottom-sheet-b8025573c433)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Sliding_Up_Panel plug-in](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel). It's very easy to set up, everything is pretty much done already.

Comment: how to integrate it with list view click I'm new with flutter

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using BottomSheet yet??

Try reading this :
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-beginners-guide-to-using-the-bottom-sheet-b8025573c433

And for making it expandable ,you can change the  BottomSheet constructor as shown:

```
 BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return new BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
      maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
      minHeight: 0.0,
      maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight * 9.0 / 16.0
    );
  }
```

If you adjust the maxHeight constraints, the bottom sheet size can be changed.

Comment: how to integrate it with list view click I'm new with flutter